# bootstrap popover not firing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have this code:

**HTML**

```
  <input type="text" 
                                data-placement="bottom" 
                                data-trigger="manual" 
                                data-content=""
                                name="momlastname" id="momlastname" 
                                ng-model="momlastname" 
                                maxlength="70" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#momlastname').keyup(function (f) {
                    console.log($(this).val().length);
                    if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
                            $('#momlastname').popover({
                                trigger:'manual',
                                content:function(){
                                    return 'Start.';
                                }
                            });
                            $('#momlastname').popover('show');
                            $('#momlastname').addClass('error');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#momlastname').popover('hide');
                    }
                });
```

When I take out the else part, it works but I need the else part too so that the popover is hidden when the field length is less than 2 or greater than 2.

Comment: So, you want the modal to be hidden if the field length is equal to 2? If that's so, you have your if statement backwards.

Comment: Your code will hide the popup whenever the field length is NOT equal to 2, and show it when it is equal to 2.

Comment: To be hidden when the field is less than 2 or greater than 2

Comment: @Brino yes but now it is not working. I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

**JSFIDDLE** https://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/xksfj23e/

To hide the popup when field length != 2 and show it otherwise, the following code works. See JSFIDDLE above.

```
$('#momlastname').keyup(function (f) {
                console.log($(this).val().length);
                if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
                        $('#momlastname').popover({
                            trigger:'manual',
                            content:function(){
                                return 'Start.';
                            }
                        });
                        $('#momlastname').popover('show');
                        $('#momlastname').addClass('error');
                }
                else {
                    $('#momlastname').popover('hide');
                }
            });
```